# Custom Font in iOS Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios

"Custom Font in iOS Keyboard Extension"
Can we develop iOS custom keyboard which supports "Times New Roman" font style?
Regards,
Suresh.

Answer (score 0):

UIFont provides by element where text inputed. It means that you can't set font in Keyboard Extension.